# Portrait and Landscape?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, landscape-portrait

I am using Xcode 6.1 and I am facing this problem.

I started by changing it's size (Width x Height) (600x1200). I put a `ScollView` and pinned it (clicking on four sides) and a View and pinned it (clicking on four sides and width and height) as well, I removed the check on both "Constraints to margins" while pinning them, I added and image to be in the top center and I marked it as "Add Missing Constraints", but it doesn't! I noticed that it puts the View as a width of 600!

I don't know if it was from the Image I added or the View, I'm mixed, help

p.s. I want it to work on all iPhones

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT8B0.jpg)

Comment: Please make clear, what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I want to put the image as you can see in the phone in the top middle, make scroll work, the scroll is working but the image not in place!

Comment: "Add missing constraints" is a hit & miss. Create your constraints explicitly.